# Как в WinRM увеличить размер стека?

Tags: powershell

Пытаемся упорядочить наши скрипты администрирования - но внезапно оказалось, что комбинация из WinRM, обработки ошибок и ScriptMethod снижает доступную глубину рекурсии драматически.

Пример для демонстрации проблемы:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {
    $object = New-Object psobject
    $object | Add-Member ScriptMethod foo {
        param($depth)
        if ($depth -eq 0) {
            throw "error"
        }
        else {
            $this.foo($depth - 1)
        }
    }

    try {
        $object.foo(5) # Работает (ошибка поймана)
    } catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception
    }

    try {
        $object.foo(6) # Сбой сценария из-за переполнения глубины вызовов.
    } catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception
    }
}
```

**ШЕСТЬ!** Всего шесть вложенных вызовов вызывают переполнение стека! Это при том, что локально хоть 200 вложенных вызовов отрабатывают нормально, без try-catch допустимая глубина увеличивается в два раза - да и обычные функции в рекурсии не так ограничены.

Есть ли способ увеличить максимальную глубину стека? Все административные права - есть.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822726/